# Best solution for Push Notifications

Tags: android, ios, .net, json, push-notification

I need to implement something that will allow me to pass a JSON from a .Net server app to mobile device, and from the mobile device back to .Net.

The JSON could be anywhere up to about 400KB in size so I need to find a solution that will ensure that the JSON can be compressed to a suitable size.

I don't have much experience in this area so was hoping someone would have some recommendations.

I was looking at PubNub but I can't see any way of getting a 400KB JSON compressed in a way that it could be passed to their channels.

Comment: [Item number 4](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Well [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm)seems such an obvious choice. Regardless of what you choose you don't need to pass 400kb of data (compressed or uncompressed) the usual practice is to pass a link to the data. Once the device receives a push notification it can look at the link and retrieve the full dataset if needed.

GCM can be used with .NET or any other programming language of your choice and it's supported on both ios and android (I am beginning to sound like an advert for google)